# 'mkdir' in a shell file cannot create directory: "Permission denied"

Tags: shell, mkdir

I have a shell script in my home folder:

*copy.sh*

```
mkdir new_folder
```

when I ran the shell script from my home folder:

```
./copy.sh
```

I got error message:

```
-bash: ./copy.sh: Permission denied
```

Why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [shell scrip run when I am root but I get a permission denied when it is invoked from a Makefile (still as root)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28332397/shell-scrip-run-when-i-am-root-but-i-get-a-permission-denied-when-it-is-invoked)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give the script execution permission:

```
chmod +x path_to_the_copy.sh
```

Comment: Another option is to call the shell command and give the script as a parameter (This is not a permanent solution), like this: `bash path_to_the_copy.sh` or if you want to have a verbose output: `bash -x path_to_the_copy.sh`

Comment: This did not seem to work for me . i still get a permission denied error